# Find which z satisfy this equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$ z^3 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{(i-1)^n} $$

How would i go about solving for $z$? I apologize for not being able to write the equation more readably.

Comment: I formatted your equation to be solved using MathJax/LaTeX.  I do not understand what $i$ is, unless you mean the purely imaginary square root of $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

First find the sum of the series on the right. Then use DeMoivre's theorem to solve for $z$.

The series is

$$\frac{1}{i-1}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{i-1}\right)^{n-1} = \frac{1}{i-1}\cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{i-1}} = \frac{1}{i} = -i$$

So $z^3 = -i$, or $z^3 = e^{-\pi i/2}$. Now you can solve for $z$.

Comment: I would probably have written it $\displaystyle z^3 = e^{-i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi)}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that no roots are missed.